# Symfony4 findAll in service return empty array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a problem : 
I get a repository in a service and I do a findAll on it, problem: I get an empty array (while my database is not). So I guess I'm doing something wrong, I hope you can enlighten me.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: thocou
 * Date: 07/03/19
 * Time: 15:05
 */

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\RentRelease;
use App\Repository\PropertyRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class RentReleaseInsertion
{
private $propertyRepository;
private $manager;

public function __construct(PropertyRepository $propertyRepository, ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->propertyRepository = $propertyRepository;
    $this->manager = $manager;
}


public function settingRentReleaseValues()
{
    $property = $this->propertyRepository->findAll();

    dd($property);

    foreach ($property as $prop) {
        $lessees = $prop->getLessees();

        foreach ($lessees as $lessee) {
            $rentRelease = new RentRelease();
            $amount = $prop->getRentExcludingCharges() + $prop->getCharges();

            $rentRelease->setRentRelease($lessee);
            $rentRelease->setAmount($amount);
            $rentRelease->setStatus('Paiement en attente');

            $this->manager->persist($rentRelease);
            $this->manager->flush();
        }
    }
}
}
```

the repository is here :

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Property;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Property|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Property|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Property[]    findAll()
 * @method Property[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PropertyRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Property::class);
}
}
```

To be honnest I don't really understand where is the problem from, even though I suspect it's a very small problem.

EDIT :

here is my entity (i don't show you getter setter because it's +500 lines but they have been generated):

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 */
class Property
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Choice({"Appartement", "Maison", "Garage", "Bureau", "Château", "Commerce"})
 * @var string
 */
private $propertyCategory;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @var string
 */
private $uniqueName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @var string
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @var string
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @Assert\Length(min = 5, minMessage = "Ce champ doit contenir 5 chiffres")
 * @Assert\Length(max = 5, maxMessage = "Ce champ doit contenir 5 chiffres")
 * @var int
 */
private $zipCode;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Country
 * @var string
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @var string
 */
private $surfaceInSquareMeter;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @var int
 */
private $numberOfPiece;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @var string
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Choice({"Meublé", "Non meublé"})
 * @var string
 */
private $rentalCategory;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("float")
 * @var float
 */
private $rentExcludingCharges;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("float")
 * @var float
 */
private $charges;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("float")
 * @var float
 */
private $purchasePrice;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="properties")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_property_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $userProperty;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Equipment", mappedBy="equipment")
 */
private $equipment;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Lessee", mappedBy="lessee")
 */
private $lessees;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "2000k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Choisisez un fichier PDF"
 * )
 */
private $pdfFile;
```

Comment: How exactly did you encounter that the array is empty? Is that exception thrown? Are you sure that you've connected to the same database where you already see rows?

Comment: I just did a dump and I saw '[]'. I'm on the good database and the table isn't empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your Entity and verify that this header is present :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 */
class Property
{
...
```

Comment: Yes that's on my entity, I already have a CRUD on this entity and it works well

Comment: Did you tried to specify the table with `@ORM\Table(name="...")`?

Comment: Did you try to specify the env on your command : ```--env=dev```

Comment: PawełNapierała I don't know what you are talking about, I will check it.

Mathieu yes, nothing different

Comment: You should have the request in the log files, it can help you to see the problem

Comment: @PawełNapierała OK i did what you told me and now I have a different error, I'll check that, thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: sorry, the error was because the name I gave was already used for another table ... so the problem is still here ...

Comment: the request is: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.property_category AS property_category_2, t0.unique_name AS unique_name_3, t0.address AS address_4, t0.city AS city_5, t0.zip_code AS zip_code_6, t0.country AS country_7, t0.surface_in_square_meter AS surface_in_square_meter_8, t0.number_of_piece AS number_of_piece_9, t0.description AS description_10, t0.rental_category AS rental_category_11, t0.rent_excluding_charges AS rent_excluding_charges_12, t0.charges AS charges_13, t0.purchase_price AS purchase_price_14, t0.pdf_file AS pdf_file_15, t0.user_property_id AS user_property_id_16 FROM property t0

Comment: So `@ORM\Table(name="property")` returns an empty result as well?

Comment: @ORM\Table(name="property") return an empty array

Comment: problem solved: it's because I'm the biggest retard earth never see, I'm working on a virtual machine but I execute the command on my real machine. Sorry for the inconvenience, thank you for your efforts.